# I can't create command with \DeclareDocumentCommand{}{omv}{}

Tags: enumitem, minted, xparse

I have to make list environment based on description that should be used to describe code functions.

Here is the prototype:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlist{funcDescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[funcDescription, 1]{itemsep=2mm, style=nextline, font=\mdseries\ttfamily, align=left}
\NewDocumentCommand{\funcitem}{O{}mv}{\item[\mintinline[#1]{#2}|#3|]}

\begin{document}

    \begin{funcDescription}
        \funcitem{c}{int printf(const char * format, ...)}
            Writes the \code{C} string pointed by format to the standard output
            (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences
            beginning with \code{\%}), the additional arguments following
            format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing
            their respective specifiers.
    \end{funcDescription}
    
\end{document}
```

It produces the

```
document.tex|32 error| Argument of \\RobustMintInline has an extra }.
document.tex|| Runaway argument?
document.tex|32 error| Paragraph ended before \\RobustMintInline was complete.
```

instead of

[image]

If I remove `O{}` from the `\funcitem` options, everything works as intended.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlist{funcDescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[funcDescription, 1]{itemsep=2mm, style=nextline, font=\mdseries\ttfamily, align=left}
\NewDocumentCommand{\funcitem}{mv}{\item[\mintinline{#1}|#2|]}

\begin{document}

    \begin{funcDescription}
        \funcitem{c}|int printf(const char * format, ...)|
            Writes the \code{C} string pointed by format to the standard output
            (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences
            beginning with \code{\%}), the additional arguments following
            format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing
            their respective specifiers.
    \end{funcDescription}
    
\end{document}
```

What is happening? How to make `\funcitem[]{}||` work with `O{}` optional argument?

(`texdoc` research on `xparse` didn't help. They only say that `v` key may be unstable, `minted` docs say that its environments has been carefully crafted to work under almost all circumstances)

##### UPDATE 1

I have been playing with the `\funcitem` realization and discovered when I use next implementation:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\funcitem}{mv}{\item[{\mintinline[tabsize=4]{#1}|#2|}]}
```

it produces the same error. So the problem isn't int the `O{}` or `o`, it is in the optional argument of `\mintinline`. Also, when I remove `\item` from `\funcitem`, and use it outside of `fundDescription` environment I get no error. What is happening?

Comment: Not sure if you made a typo in your MWE or in your original code, but you're missing a square bracket in your definition of `\funcitem`. The broken syntax highlighting makes this very clear.

Comment: you can not use verbatim commands such as `\mininline` in the argument of another command

Comment: @bonk Fixed. Actually in my setup I ran correct command. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then why the `\NewDocumentCommand{\funcitem}{mv}{\item[\mintinline{#1}|#2|]}` works? It has something to do with `O{}` optional argument. I cant use `o` because when no optional argument provided, `#1` becomes `-NoValue-` which makes `minted` go error, so I provide default value of `o` with `O{}`. I updated the post, please check it.

Comment: mintinline can not work in that position. for some content you may not get an error but it can never work, just as if you use `\verb|abc|` it would work but just act like `\texttt` but if you use other content such as `\verb|{%}|`  you will see errors as the characters are not handled verbatim

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry, I may not understand something, but the `\funcitem{text}|{_?\\%}|` works as well. Why? I am confused/

Comment: you used v so the characters are read verbatim

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So it seems that `mintinline` can work in that position. I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, putting any verbatim-like command into the argument of another command is not supported, and at best will work 'accidentally'. That said, the specific issue here has a different cause, unrelated to verbatim.

'Classical' optional argument grabbing in LaTeX does *not* match levels, so `\item[\mintinline[#1]{#2}|#3|]` results in `\item` reading `\mintinline[#1` as it's optional argument. The `\mintinline` command then tries to read an optional argument, but fails to find the end `]` and so you get a low-level error. Had `\item` been defined using `ltcmd` (which does do matching), this would not happen.

The solution to nesting optional arguments is to use braces to hide the 'inner' one:

```latex
\item[{\mintinline[#1]{#2}|#3|}]
```

That will solve the issue at hand, though the verbatim part will remain a worry.

Comment: I just finished writing an update about discovery that the problem is not in `O{}`. Thank You for explaining stuff well!